# Regex or alternative to strip string into variables to use in URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have something like this `SW-763-20200622-XXX-YYY`.

I need to create a URL link that has a static string + parts from the string above in a certain way - e.g. for this particular case `https://www.static/SW/763/2020/06/22`

So far I have something like this, that already shows `static part` + `SW/763`:

```
  <Link
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
    data-qa="link-report"
    href=
      {
      `https://www.static/${
        something.identifier.replace(/-/g, "/").slice(0, 6)}'
      }
  >
    Link
  </Link>
```

I played around with Regex and could also retrieve the year with `/\d{4}(?=\d{4})/g` but this approach means I would have to add to the current code, more lines with replace/regex to catch the year (with the regex I mentioned) and other(s) for the month/day also separated by `/` (`20200622`).

Wondering if there is a better way to do it either with a more complete regex or just a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the specific parts, and use the groups creating the expected format with replace.

```
^([A-Z]{2})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\b.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xWG5rz/1)

```js
const regex = /^([A-Z]{2})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\b.*/gm;
const s = `SW-763-20200622-XXX-YYY`;

console.log(s.replace(regex, `https://www.static/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5`))
```

Comment: I can understand your regex. The replace with the grouping seems a good idea. Thank you

Comment: Just a heads up that I ended up just changing this bit (\d{3}) to (\d{3,}) because later on, I've noticed it could be 3 or more digits. In case it helps someone else :)